# SQL Developer new column resets identity column setting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, identity-column

I am running SQL Developer Version 18.1.0.095 on a MacBook Pro. Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I’ve encountered an issue regarding sequences and triggers which seems unusual and I’d like to know if it’s a bug.

If you use SQL Developer to create a table, and visit the identity column tab on the table properties screen, to set up auto incremented Primary Key values via an auto generated sequence and trigger pair, everything works fine in terms of auto generated values. But if you ever come back to the table and add an additional column, the identity column value is set back to 'none' (silently, in the background) and the database returns 'cannot insert NULL' type errors because there is no longer an auto generated value being created for the column identified in the trigger. It may also be the case that if you reset that drop down, duplicate triggers and sequences are created. eg triggername1, triggername2.

If you manually create a sequence and trigger pair for a given table, there is no issue with adding extra columns later in the table's life (which seems more reasonable). It may that standard workflow requires you to archive and recreate tables each time you add a new column, but this seems a lot of work and a less desirable outcome than just being able to add columns without any impact on a primary key column. So this makes me wonder which is the default behaviour and if the resetting of triggers via the identity column workflow is a bug.

For now I’ll stick with manual sequences and triggers but I’m interested to know more about this.

Comment: You could see if it's been raised [on the SQL Developer forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/sql_developer) or on My Oracle Support; or could raise a service request to report it as a bug. But I'd suggest you get the latest version of SQL Developer first and see if it still behaves the same way.

Comment: ... although, in 18.3 at least, doing this through the table creation wizard only allows the 'identity column' to be a trigger/sequence pair, not a real 12c-type 'generated as identity' column, which is interesting in itself. But having set up a trigger/sequence pair like that, adding a new column doesn't then lose those in this version, if I'm following your steps properly.

Comment: 'if you ever come back' - do you mean you click 'OK' and create the table, and then you come back via the Edit dialog? if so, I don't understand. If you mean, you click around the create table dialog and THEN come back to the PK/identity clause stuff and it's messed up - yes, that is a known bug, where the table create dialog properties get reset if you click around

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have checked my organisation's software catalogue and can see that it offers version 18.4 so will make some time in the next few days to upgrade and re test. And thatjeffasmith. By come back I mean create the table, set up auto key values via the identity column, close it down, or start using the table, but then for example 2 days later, realise I need to add one more column to the end of the table. That's when the identity column spontaneously resets and stops adding values to the PK column.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in SQL Developer 19.2.1.247 against an Oracle Cloud database.  Every time I open the edit panel for a table, the Identity Column's Trigger and Sequence are showing a new number.